# Firefox : Specifying location of bookmarks

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When adding a new bookmark with Ctrl+D in Firefox, it used to ask me where to put it in terms of bookmark directory structure.

However, recently it's not even bothering to ask me and put the bookmark under the bookmark menu by default.
Then I always need to open the bookmark menu and drag & drop to the right sub folder, which is quite tedious.

Is there any way to make Firefox ask me where to put the bookmark everytime I add one?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+D twice?

Comment: I just tried, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: So you don't see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k1eil.png) anymore when you press Ctrl+D?

Comment: A similar problem solved: http://support.mozilla.org/et/questions/901946

Comment: @Karan Exactly.

Comment: @JüriRuut Disabling the hardware acceleration didn't help, but it seems like there maybe some add-ons causing this problem..

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get it resolved.

Just reinstalled firefox and add-ons from scratch, (which I wanted to avoid..) and it works well now.

Still not very sure what was causing that problem.

Answer (score -2):

Dunno if this can help, but I found out the add-on [COMPACT MENU 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/compact-menu-2/) to be conflictual with the feature.

I fixed the problem just removing the add-on.

Comment: What do you mean by "conflictual"?  Was it causing the same problem as stated in the question?